# Select Quads and remove them

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

Can someone please tell me how to select the inner quads and delete them, basically I'm learning to implement [A*](http://arongranberg.com/astar/docs/getstarted2.php) and want to create a navmesh that will later be used in unity.

Here's the image. 
[image: What I have done]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could depend also on the resulting mesh you wish to obtain, eg:

- a big plane with only 4 vertices?
- a big empty plane with only 4 vertices?
- the plane as it is but without inner quads?

see a couple of example below, using dissolve commands

with dissolve vertices, but you get a plane of more than 4 verts

[image]

[image]

or with dissolve edges

[image]

[image]

...you get the idea...

[edit]
in the tutoarial you are following inthe link above, it says

"Create a plane, subdivide it two times and then remove the inner four quads."

well,

- first, it is wrong: to get the subdivided plane I see in that image, which has a total of 16 face after subdivision, you have to subdivide the plane 3 times, not 2.

then it seems to convert those inner 4 faces into a a big square.

so you can switch to select faces mode, selet the inner 4 faces, and simply "dissolve faces"... like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do I select specific quads?

Comment: As shown above, select vertices or edges. But you can also do this: select all quads, switch to select edges and press CTRL-X

Comment: Nope, I don't think i'll be able to do it

Comment: It says, subdivide the plane two times and then remove inner four quads.
And I don't even know how to select and remove!

Comment: "it says"... Are you meaning in the the link you put in the post? I'll check it out. If you try on a simple quad subdivided, my method works, but in that tutorial, something could be different, let me check it. OK. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Making the shape pictured below (a plane with a hole in it) is very easy.
[image: resulting mesh]

All you have to do is select the center vertex and delete it, with <kbd>Delete</kbd> > *Vertices* (or <kbd>X</kbd> > *Vertices* ).

[image: animated gif - deleting a vertex]